# Web service client can not be created by jaxws:wsimport utility [binding.xsd]

Tags: web, service, binding, xsd, client

I'm trying to consume a web service but I can't even start. I get an error as soon as I include the Web Service. I have researched and found similar errors but not this one. I hope you guys know a way around this:

[image]

I can't see the methods I should under Web Service References -> info, the 'info' appears with an X, see the image:

[image]

So I can't see the methods. A friend gave me his project and compiled it and got the same error, but it worked. I tried copy-pasting the methods into my project and it worked as well. The thing is how am I supposed to use the methods if I can't know them?

Thankyou in advance

Comment: Have you solved this problem, please?

Comment: @sada Sadly, no, I never managed to solve this error